# why does gsub not replace NA

Tags: r

**Aim**

Replace `NA` with `"Nothing"` in character vector

**Input**

```
data<-c(NA, NA, "SupineAcid", NA, NA, NA, "UprightAcid", "UprightAcid", 
NA, NA, "UprightAcid", NA, "UprightAcid", NA, NA, "UprightAcid", 
"TotalAcid", NA, NA, NA)
```

**Attempts**

```
gsub(NA,"dd",data)
```

This leads to all the results being NA

I've also tried with `"NA"` and `fixed=TRUE` but the same issue.

Comment: Like I said, tried that one

Comment: You could try `data[is.na(data)]="dd"`

Comment: OK that worked. I didn't know you couldnt gsub NA

Comment: @Lamia Post as answer please

Comment: @SebastianZeki That's because there is nothing to gsub in an NA value.  It's a value that saying "hey this is missing".  When you use gsub you're saying I want to replace this particular string (or regex) with a certain value.  Your gsub isn't matching NA because there is nothing to match - it's missing!  So you need to call out the NAs directly using `is.na`

Answer (score 5):

In order to change the `NA` elements in your vector, you can use the `is.na` function:

```
data[is.na(data)] = "dd"

 "dd"          "dd"          "SupineAcid"  "dd"          "dd"          "dd"          "UprightAcid"
 "UprightAcid" "dd"          "dd"          "UprightAcid" "dd"          "UprightAcid" "dd"         
 "dd"          "UprightAcid" "TotalAcid"   "dd"          "dd"          "dd"
```

Answer (score 5):

NA is not the same as "NA".  If you make sure that both the first and third arguments use "NA" then it will work.

```
sub("NA", "dd", paste(data))
```

Alternately

```
ifelse(is.na(data), "dd", data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `replace`

```
replace(data, is.na(data), 'dd')
```